# Latexdiff not working in Windows (Unescaped left brace in regex)

Tags: miktex, latexdiff, perl

Because the miktex repo is down today, I tried installed the latexdiff package manually. 
I am using windows 10 by the way.

Here are the steps I followed.

1. Installed strawberry perl from http://strawberryperl.com/
2. Installed latexdiff by downloading latexdiff from https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages
3. Created folder C:\miktex_pkgs
4. Moved latexdiff.tar.lzma, miktex-zzdb1-2.9.tar.lzma, and miktex-zzdb2-2.9.tar.lzma and ulem.tar.lzma into the C:\miktex_pkgs folder
5. Opened Miktex Settings (Admin), clicked on packges tab, changed Package Repository to C:\miktex_pkgs
6. Upon running latexdiff -h on the command line I get the following messages shown in the picture below and also when I run latexdiff old.tex new.dex > diff.tex, the diff.tex file is all corrupted.

[image]

What is going on?

Comment: The deprecation messages are just warnings and should not interfere with the function under current Perl (the problem is already fixed in the development version, so will disappear with the next latexdiff release). With the corrupted diff file you have thus another problem but there is not enough information to help you. Is the diff file just complete garbage or does it simply not parse properly? Try to create a minimum example and post all three files (old.tex, new.tex, diff.tex) (I don't have access to MikTeX, so probably won't be able to help you further but others might).

Comment: Thanks @frederik, there were so many problems in the output file (issues with UL@Word and DLadd and DLbegin stuff that I just gave up. I corrected the errors in the PERL file by looking putting the '\' character in front of the { also. I think the problems I am getting come from latexdiff not handling my original input file very well, I am using Lyx. I also tried using Texniccenter to compile the diff.tex file and it also failed.